# Texbox value binding in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have sample XAML with `TextBox` code as:

## XAML

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
         Text="{Binding Path=Remarks, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         BorderThickness="0.5" Margin="0" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White"  />

<Button CommandParameter="{Binding ListExecActionId}" 
        Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=TaskPerformanceModel.ActivityAction_comment}"
        Content="Save"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0,0,0" Height="Auto" />
```

## View Model:

```
public string Remarks
{
    get { return _remarks; }
    set
    {               
        if (!string.Equals(_remarks, value))
        {
            _remarks = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Remarks"); 
        }
    }
}
```

---

ActivityAction_coment as follows

```
public RelayCommand<object> ActivityAction_comment
{
    get
    {
        if (_ActivityAction_comment == null)
        {
            _ActivityAction_comment = new RelayCommand<object>((ExecActionId) => ActivityComment(ExecActionId));
        }
        return _ActivityAction_comment;
    }
}
```

---

```
private void ActivityComment(object _id)
{
    try
    {
        using (DataContext objDataContext = new DataContext(DBConnection.ConnectionString))
        {
            ListExecutionAction tblListExec = objDataContext.ListExecutionActions.Single(p => p.Id == Convert.ToInt32(_id));
            **tblListExec.Remarks = Remarks; // Not getting Remarks value from Textbox**
            objDataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "TaskExecution:ActivityComment");
    }
}
```

I am unable to get textbox (Remarks) value in view model. Always getting `""`.
can any one help me out please.

For more clarity I am updating view:

```
<ListView.View>                    
                  <GridViewColumn >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActionDescription}" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                    <ToggleButton Name="button">
                                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                <TextBlock>Remarks!!</TextBlock>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=button}" StaysOpen="False" Width="250" Height="100">
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Background="LightBlue" Text="{Binding ActionDescription}"></TextBlock>

                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Text="Comments:" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent" />
                                            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Center"                                                                                                                                
                                                     Text="{Binding Path=Remarks, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                 BorderThickness="0.5" Margin="0" Height="50"/>

                                            <!--Text="{Binding Remarks, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Text="{Binding Path=Remarks, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"    DataContext="{Binding CollectionOfListQueue}" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White"-->

                                            <Button CommandParameter="{Binding ListExecActionId}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=TaskPerformanceModel.ActivityAction_comment}" Content="Save"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0,0,0"  Height="Auto" />
                                                <Button Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,0,0" Height="Auto" />
                                            <!--</Grid>-->
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Popup>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
```

Comment: think about Datacontext binding

Comment: What does the output screen say about that property?

Comment: Your code looks fine and should be working. Did you debug if your databinding works?

Comment: Can you show your `ActivityAction_comment` command?

Comment: Also, why do you have your `TextBox` content invisible? `Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" `

Comment: ActivityAction_comment code edited in the Question

Comment: where is the datacontext of the view being set?

Comment: DataContext is set as follows:
<Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="TaskPerformanceModel" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
    </Window.DataContext>

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on your `Remarks` set ? You know it's getting updated ?

Comment: @linuxrocks it doesn't really need to be "invisible" if the window/control background isn't white.

Comment: @Hussain: Is the ActivityAction_comment and Remarks properties defined in the same class?

Comment: @mm8 yes both ActivityAction_comment and Remarks properties are defined in the same class

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez I kept the breakpoint at Remarks property but value not updating.

Comment: @Hussain you have a breakpoint in `if (!string.Equals(_remarks, value))` and it doesn't stop there ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez I had kept breakpoint in if (!string.Equals(_remarks, value)) and it doesn't stop here at the time of loading. And value not updating from here itself.

Comment: @Hussein: What does the TaskPerformanceModel property of the view model locator return?

Comment: @mm8 TaskPerformanceModel is returning corresponding ID of (ListExecActionId)

Comment: @Hussain: That makes no sense. What's the DataContext of the TextBox then? What's the parent panel of the TextBox and the Button?

Comment: @mm8 I had updated  XAML part view. Against each dynamic checkbox I need to raise popup having textbox. On Button click need to save textbox value (Remarks) in database. Plz let me know what need to change in textbox properties and model RaisePropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to `ActivityAction_comment` and `Remarks` properties of the view model:

```
<Button CommandParameter="{Binding ListExecActionId}"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.ActivityAction_comment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" 
        Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0,0,0"  Height="Auto" />
```

You need to the same for the Remarks binding

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.Remarks, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" ... />
```

You should then be able to get the value in the `TextBox` using the `Remarks` source property:

```
private void ActivityComment(object _id)
{
    try
    {
        using (DataContext objDataContext = new DataContext(DBConnection.ConnectionString))
        {
            ListExecutionAction tblListExec = objDataContext.ListExecutionActions.Single(p => p.Id == Convert.ToInt32(_id));
            string remarks = Remarks;
            objDataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "TaskExecution:ActivityComment");
    }
}
```

Comment: After removing source from binding button click event not working.

Comment: Do you see the ActionDescription? Please post the complete code of your classes.

Comment: Yes I can see ActionDescription. Posted complete class.

Comment: @Hussain: What is the ListView's ItemsSource bound to?

Comment: It is binding as ItemsSource="{Binding TemplateView}"

Comment: @Hussain: See my edit. You should be able to bind to the `ActivityAction_comment` property of the parent view model using a `{RelativeSource}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179645/discussion-between-hussain-and-mm8).